# Local installation of express-generator

Tags: node.js, express

I have installed express-generator locally by below command.

```
npm install express-generator
```

Can I utilize this module to generate structure in same folder.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just use path `./node_modules/express-generator/bin/express-cli.js`